# Custom Delegate Methods Not Working iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a custom delegate method to update the background colour of a ViewController. I cannot get the delegate method to respond. Here is my code:

VASettingsView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@class VASettingsView;

@protocol VASettingsViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)setNewBackgroundColour:(GLKVector4)newColour;
@end

@interface VASettingsView : UIView {
    id <VASettingsViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *blackBackgroundButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;

@property GLKVector4 backgroundColourSetting;

// Set delegate method
@property (nonatomic,weak)id delegate;

- (IBAction)blackButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

VASettingsView.m

```
#import "VASettingsView.h"

@implementation VASettingsView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)blackButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.backgroundColourSetting = GLKVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [delegate setNewBackgroundColour:self.backgroundColourSetting];
}

@end
```

VARendererViewController.h

```
@class VA_CASFrame;
@class VA_Character;
@class VA_Orbit_Camera;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "VASettingsView.h"

@interface VARendererViewController : GLKViewController <VASettingsViewDelegate>
{
    // Code

}
```

VARendererViewController.m

ViewDidLoad

```
// Setup UIView to be delegate
VASettingsView *settingsView = [[VASettingsView alloc] init];
settingsView.delegate = self;
```

setNewBackgroundColour

```
- (void)setNewBackgroundColour:(GLKVector4)newColour{

    self.backgroundColour = GLKVector4Make(newColour.x,
                                           newColour.y,
                                           newColour.z,
                                           newColour.w
                                           );
    NSLog(@"STOP");
}
```

Storyboard:

[image: Container and UIView]

I cannot reach the setNewBackgroundColour and have been looking for answers for hours. I cannot see what I have done wrong?

Sam

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your IBAction, what is delegate set to at that moment?

Comment: Shouldn't `@property (nonatomic,weak)id delegate;` be `@property (nonatomic,weak)id<VASettingsViewDelegate> delegate;`? Also, don't manually set instance variables anymore, use the auto-synthesized property `self.delegate` and get rid of `id<VASettingsViewDelegate> delegate;`;

Comment: How are you making the view for VASettingsView? Storyboard? Xib? And  how do you get it on screen?

Comment: After you set `settingsView.delegate = self;` do you then display the `settingsView`?  If it's not added to your UI, it won't handle actions.

Comment: I create the settingsView using storyboard. It is a UIView that is displayed within a UIContainer. Here is the code:// Settings button pressed
- (void)settingsButtonTapped{
    if (settingsContainerView.hidden == FALSE){
        settingsContainerView.hidden = TRUE;
    }else{
        settingsContainerView.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are alloc init'ing a new instance of VASettingsView in VARendererViewController, rather than getting a pointer the one that you're putting on screen. Since you don't show how you get VASettingsView on screen, or how you create its view, it's only a guess.

After edit:

Instead of,

```
VASettingsView *settingsView = [[VASettingsView alloc] init];
settingsView.delegate = self;
```

Try this,

```
VASettingsView *settingsView = self.childViewControllers[0];
SettingsView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: My UIView is displayed within a UIContainer

Comment: @samb90 does that mean that VASettingsView is on screen at the same time as VARenderer? If so, then the problem is what I said -- you are creating a different instance from the one where you click the button. If its in a container view, then you can get a pointer to it with self.childViewControllers[0].

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what I mean. I'm not sure this will work because I don't know what you mean by "It is a UIView that is displayed within a UIContainer". If you mean it's a controller embedded in e container view, it should work.

Comment: Hey, I did try that method with no luck still. I have attatched a picture of my storybaord with the question to try and visualise the container and the associated UIView

Comment: If you add the code I posted, and do a log NSLog(@"%@",settingsView), what does it give?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the iOS 6.0 SDK, the problem could be that the delegate property is not linked to the instance variable `delegate`. Apple changed the standard so that if you don't `@synthesize` the property, the corresponding instance variable will be called `_delegate`.

To fix your problem, try either synthesizing the `delegate` property or accessing it by calling `self.delegate` in the `saveButtonPressed:` method.

Comment: I have tried both delegate and _delegate, as well as self.delegate with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you declared a local variable inside a method, and set its delegate.  By the time you exit `viewDidLoad`, that variable disappears.  You need to make `VASettingsView *settingsView` an instance variable (i.e. declare it in your implementation), and then set its delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have updated the code with your idea and it still is not working

Comment: In other words, did you set the class of the view to VASettingsView in your storyboard, then connect it to an outlet in your VARendererViewController?  (I didn't realize before what setup you were using-- this should fix it)